# How to show window with "Select file" in objective-C cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, file, select, nsworkspace

I've got some action in my application on OS X where I have to select file from finder. I want to display window like: "Open file". I know that this let me open url with path:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:NSHomeDirectory() isDirectory:YES]];
```

But how to show window with "Select" button. This window should let me to get info about selected file.

How can I do this correctly?

Thank you for help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open File Dialog Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1640419/open-file-dialog-box)

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but `NSOpenPanel` is the standard UI for selecting files.

Comment: Thank you. `NSOpenPanel` is right class to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Perception and @omz gives me good answer. Answer is `NSOpenPanel`.

Answer (score 6):

The code for previous answers :

```
NSOpenPanel *op = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
op.canChooseFiles = YES;
op.canChooseDirectories = YES;
[op runModal];
self.txtFilePath.stringValue = [op.URLs firstObject];
```

in op.URLs you can find paths for all files you just selected.

Answer (score 2):

Building on EderYif's answer, the following doesn't produce a compiler warning and also removes the 'file://' part of the returned filename.

```
NSOpenPanel *op = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[op setCanChooseFiles:true];
[op setCanChooseDirectories:true];
[op runModal];

NSString* file = [[op.URLs firstObject] absoluteString];
NSString* fixedFile = [file stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://"
                                                      withString:@""];
[[self textFilePath] setStringValue:fixedFile];
```